# Make relative background image paths absolute with Grunt SASS?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

Im using Grunt SASS
https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass

Is it possible to convert my image paths to be absolute? So if I write this:

```
.something {
 background: url(../icon.png);
}
```

I would like the compiled CSS to be:

```
.something {
 background: url(www.mysite.com/images/icon.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with grunt css url replace:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-css-url-replace

However this isnt ideal. Running an additional task will be slower and I expect this will mess up my source maps. An add on / config setting for grunt sass would be better but I cant seem to find one.